# Display Information from 2 models in one table MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

I have 2 models: Entity and Trust

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Referral")]
    public int ReferralId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DirectorshipStartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime FirstBillingDate { get; set; }

    public BillingBasis BillingBasis { get; set; }
    public int BillingBasisId { get; set; }

    public FeeType FeeType { get; set; }
    public int FeeTypeId { get; set; }

    // Relationships

    public Trust Trust { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Associated Trust")]
    public int TrustId { get; set; }

    public Structure Structure { get; set; }

    public int? StructureId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public List<int> ServicesIds { get; set; }
}
```

and Trust

```
public class Trust
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Structure Structure { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Associated Structure")]
    public int? StructureId { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to display the data from both these models in a single table so that they are searchable and viewable in one table. Both of these models can be a client and should be displayed to the user when they are browsing clients. An entity is usually owned by a trust.

One further issue I'd like clarification on is that these two models together make up a structure model. I create a loop by having a structure have an entity and trust model because the entity is also linked to the trust. When a trust is deleted the entity itself does not need to get deleted. So by removing ON DELETE CASCADE for the TRUST entity does this remove the loop?

**--EDIT--**

Since the view will just be displaying basic information about each item, because they have similar properties such as name, and structure, should I create a view that holds IEnumerable Name, IEnumerable